# getting the list of facebook friend ordered by name using c# sdk

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

iwork on wepp app that communicatte with facebook , i was retrieve a list of friends of a users and their informations , and then i must sort it by name, please there is any easy method to sort them by name , thanks for your help . here is the code that  used
        ViewBag.access_token = _fb.AccessToken;
        dynamic myInfo = _fb.Get("/me/friends");
        ViewBag.info = myInfo;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Facebook query language. Something like this:

```
SELECT name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid = me()
OR uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ORDER BY name
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/